# How to make a multiple button on a single onClick count in react ts?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, increment

I had this problem several counts to be increment upon click.

```
let count = [{id: 1, value 0}, {id: 2, value 0}]

const [counter,setCounter] = useState(counter)

increment = () => {
   I want to set counter value depends on the button click and the counter will add 1 only to the specific count above.
}

return <div>
         <input type='text' value='count1'>{count1}</h2> <- I know that this does not work
         <button onClick={increment()}>+</button>
         <input type='text' value='count1'>{count2}</h2>
         <button onClick={increment()}>+</button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use an object as your state instead of an int

Comment: Do you mean this?  
const [counter, setCounter] = useState({ count1: 0, count2: 0})

Comment: yes. and then when you set the counter, reset the entire object: `setCounter({count1: 2, ...counter})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're exactly trying to do, but I think this should help you out

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
    let count = {
        1: 0,
        2: 0
    };
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(count);
    const increment = (id) => {
        setCounter({ ...counter, [id]: counter[id] + 1 })
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type='text' id="1" value={counter[1]}></input>
            <button onClick={() => { increment(1) }}>+</button>
            <input type='text' id="2" value={counter[2]}></input>
            <button onClick={() => { increment(2) }}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can run the codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-mountain-bmkgi